# ZeroMQ Callbacks for Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala, zeromq

I'm looking for any wrapper for ZeroMQ for Java/Scala. I want to add callbacks to sockets, but by default zmq doesn't provide this feature. Only blocking operation 'recv'. Another way is to create loop and user Poller, but maybe exists some other solutions?

Comment: You may want to have a look at Akka and specifically at akka-zeromq.

http://akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/zeromq.html

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a simple Actor that would take in a callback as a constructor arg and then just sit in a:

```
while( running ) { 
  callback ( subscriber.recv( 0 ).asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]] ) 
}
```

If the speed is not a requirement, you can also look at [AKKA ZeroMQ](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/zeromq.html) module, it follows a traditional non blocking message passing. However I found it a lot slower that a vanilla JZMQ.

Comment: similar to an example of a [ZeroMqReceiver](https://github.com/tolitius/market-watch/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/gitpod/subscriber/zeromq/ZeroMqReceiver.scala), but with also passing in a callback as a constructor arg